# Express knex migrations do not create database tables

Tags: postgresql, express, knex.js

I am using knex with express as a backend ..
This is the *knexfile*

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
      directory: './src/knex/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './src/knex/seeds'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};
```

I could connect to the database and I have tested that from my express .. and I can as well create migrations using `npx knex`

and the `cli` migrate successfully only on the terminal give green successful messages... But still, the DB has zero tables. no migrations table or any tables .. i have even delete the database and recreate another one ... it seems like the `cli` does not connect with the actual Postgres server ..
Any Idea.

a user migration

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', function (table) {
    table.increments();
    table.string('email').notNull();
    table.string('password').notNull();
    table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp('deleted_at');
  });
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the client for postgresql should be 'pg' and not 'postgresql'
try changing it in both development and production

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow .. keep the focus, wish you a high score